# SwiftUI StoreKit prefersPromotionalIcon not showing icon

Tags: swiftui, in-app-purchase, storekit

When implementing the additions to **SwiftUI** with **StoreKit**, I'm trying to use the new [ProductView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/productview) and [StoreView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/storeview), with Promotional Icons: `init(id:prefersPromotionalIcon:)`

But they do not load the Promotional Icon, even if it is already added on App Store Connect and my **StoreKit Configuration File** has been synched.

Everything about the products load fine, except the Promotional Icon.

Testing on the Simulator. I have followed the WWDC 23 session where they give an example of this but I have exactly the same setup as they mention there.

## Question

Do I need to wait until the Promotional Icon has been approved by Apple (this is a new App with a new In-App Purchase)?

Or am I missing something on my configuration?

## Code

This is my implementation, not showing the icon as expected

```swift
ProductView(id: "[my purchase id]", prefersPromotionalIcon: true)
```

Answer (score 2):

After releasing the app where I implemented this new **SwiftUI** functionality, and the In-App Purchase promotions being accepted, I learned:

- Promotional Icons **work** as expected in an App downloaded from the App Store.
- Debugging on the simulator keeps **not showing** the Promotional Icons, even after they have been approved.

`Xcode 15.0.1 (15A507)`

Comment: During development I shortly saw the image in the #Preview, but at some point it never showed up. Okay, I was hoping it works after review. **Unfortunately, the promotional images still don’t show up, even after releasing the update and approving the IAP’s by Apple.** Neither on macOS nor iOS. Any idea what this could cause?

Comment: @alexkaessner The review process for IAP is messy and flaky; after it is accepted wait a few hours; and the IAP may have been approved but maybe **not** the Promotional Image. Or maybe they didn't even look at the Promotional Image (**this has happened to me a few times**). Try removing the image, and add it again, update the title or description (maybe even just add a "." at the end), and send for review again. Just updating the image may not work, is best to also modify the title or description, otherwise review will not be triggered properly.

Comment: @alexkaessner also make sure to test on the downloaded from the App Store (or built for Release). Debug apps will probably not show promotional images.

Comment: Thanks for that hint, I’ve checked again and indeed the image was not accepted by the review team. Went a little weird in the initial review and for whatever reason they only set the texts for sale. Anyway, now it works and for others double check your ASC.